# Why is the heap in Go executable?

Tags: go, memory-management, operating-system, heap-memory, exploit

I recently read this article http://codearcana.com/posts/2012/05/06/securing-and-exploiting-go-binaries.html
which claims in Go that the heap is executable. This raises a few different questions for me about the interaction between the runtime and the operating system.

In C, when a program needs space on the heap, it makes a call to malloc, which in turn calls sbrk which gives it memory. As far as I know in C the heap is read-write only.

Why is the heap in Go executable? What is different about the application - OS interaction in Go then in C?

Thanks

Comment: Nothing in the C standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) suggests that its heap is not executable. It is a quality of implementation issue (and the C heap could be executable on some systems). BTW, on my system, `malloc` may -and often does, for big memory zones- use `mmap` (not only `sbrk`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [heap is no longer executable](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/5a8b7dc6d009bd95f5904b4250107ef57c163c22).

Code was generated at runtime for function literals prior to Go 1.1, thus requiring an executable heap. Function calls were [revamped in Go 1.1](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1bMwCey-gmqZVTpRax-ESeVuZGmjwbocYs1iHplK-cjo/pub) to eliminate the need for an executable heap and to provide other benefits.

Answer (score 5):

> Why is the heap in Go executable?

Go heap is not executable since 2013.